# Android Intent how and when should i use FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED

Tags: android, android-intent

I encounter this flag - `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` paired with `FLAG_NEW_TASK`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.applicationA", "com.applicationA.Activity1"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
startActivity(intent);
```

This was in the following context:
1. The browser application recognized a phone number.
2. User can long press it and get a context menu with a "dial" option.
3. the browser then fires the above intent to open the dialer.

I have read the documentation for this flags over and over again, and tried playing with it, changing the activities affinities and  still have no clue as to what should be the expected behavior here.

Any help is appreciated.